# AND condition not working in Access for WHERE

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query where I want the totals that are null to be set to $0 but the issue is that some rows are just blank in the total column and shouldn't be set to zero as they're just breaks in the spreadsheet. So I'm trying to get the totals that are null to set to $0 where there's also a group number in the column next to the total column.

Here is my query

```
UPDATE COBCoversheet, COVERSHEET1 
SET Total = '$0.00'
WHERE (COBCoversheet.Number = COVERSHEET1.Field1) 
  AND (COBCoversheet.Total IS NULL);
```

I also tried,

```
UPDATE COBCoversheet 
INNER JOIN COVERSHEET1 
   ON COBCoversheet.Number = COVERSHEET1.Field1 
SET Total = '$0.00'
WHERE (COBCoversheet.Number = COVERSHEET1.Field1) 
  AND (COBCoversheet.Total IS NULL)
```

Neither worked. I am not an SQL master but I feel that I know a good amount so any explanation would help! Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you checked that COBCoversheet.Total is not returning empty or blank spaces rather than nulls?

Comment: @WillReid It's just telling me I'm about to update 0 zeros which shouldn't be true

Comment: @JoeC I thought that could be the case but when I do a basic UPDATE COBCoversheet SET Total = '$0.00' WHERE Total IS NULL, it updates the columns just fine (except it also updates those blank rows I don't want updated)

Comment: Try putting the where and the and inside the same set of parens. Where ( ... and ... ).

Comment: I would go with the inner join.  I don't think this is your problem but having the join clause in the where clause is at least redundant.  There must be some kind of mismatch between Number and Field1 because your statement looks ok syntax wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE COBCoversheet 
INNER JOIN COVERSHEET1 ON COBCoversheet.Number = COVERSHEET1.Field1 
SET Total = '$0.00'
WHERE COBCoversheet.Total IS NULL
```

If it says "about to update 0 row(s)" then there is a problem with your data, it isn't validating as a NULL value (perhaps the value is a space or empty)

Comment: The field is data type currency so when I try Total = '' it says data type mismatch. How do I check for empty without IS NULL?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that is a boolean validation `IsEmpty([Field])`

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was deleting the totals before resetting them with the new totals. To avoid the null situation, I just imported the spreadsheet as is (null values = $-), and I did

`UPDATE COBCoversheet SET Total = '$0.00'
WHERE Total = '$-';`

So as long as the imported spreadsheet always has $- for $0 then I should be good running the query. Thank you all!!